# How to configure my application for a suitable AWS S3 storage plan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Ruby on Rails application offers users to write short text messages and upload images. 
I set a daily upload limit of **7 images** per user and I created a background job to delete once a month all images older than 30 days. 
I also set a limit of **300 users** for my application.

Even considering that an image rarely exceeds 1 MB of size (and often is far from that), I would anyway take **1 MB** as the average image size, if you think this is a sensible approximation.

- 7 images per user it is 7x300 = 2100 daily images uploaded to AWS from all users.
- 2100 daily images mean 2100x30 = 63000 monthly images uploaded to AWS
- 63000 images per month of 1 MB each require about 62 GB. I would take 100 GB as a safety value.

I inserted in the [simple monthly calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) the following values in the *standard storage* section for *US-East (Virginia)*:

- Storage: 100 GB
- PUT/COPY/POST/LIST Requests: 70000 (instead of 63000)
- GET and Other Requests: 2000000 (instead of 63000x30=1890000)

NOTE: 1890000 as far as I understand can express daily requests considering all users using the application once a day per 30 days, and thus every day asking AWS to show their images. Is that correct?

What I get is an estimated monthly bill of 3.31 $: is this a sensible estimate? 
If instead my estimate is wrong, because I missed some point, considering that my monthly budget can be between 5 $ and 10 $, how would you suggest me to configure my application (number of users, number of images per day and their size limit)?

Comment: Its aproximate and seems good, But Why dont you use life cycle of S3 to configure lifecycle of each file. That might lower your cost. Because there are charges associated with different storage classes (S3, S3-IS, Glacier ). Yor calculation seems good but why dont you make your file transfer to s3-IA after 7 days and from s3-IA to Glacier after 20 days and delete from glacier after 60 days or something like that. by doing this you can save storage of S3 and if in any case anu user want to access old file then you can access those files from S3-IA.

Comment: After skim-reading the related documentation, I think it is a really good advice. I will study object lifecycle at AWS S3, considering that my application shows only the last 100 posts (and relative images), and that previous posts and images are not retrieved from database and AWS.

Comment: and you dont have to write your backend logic to delete the files, after the expiration file will be automatically deleted. Everything depends on your logic that when file move from one class to another and when to delete. Different s3 class has its own pricing. Good luck